# Could not find installable ISAM

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a setup a connection to an access database inside Excel to update some reports. But I am not getting this error when I try to refresh the workbook: Could not find installable ISAM.

Here is the connection string I am using:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=\\0datblaset\BlaSet\BLA-AssetMangment.mdb;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause (at least from what I've found in my own experience) is the last piece of the connection string:

```
Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False
```

If you, or your user community, is using the file between versions, say for example you're using 2013 and your users are using 2010, then later version add a couple of additional parameters to the connection string that earlier version don't recognize.

See this link for more info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3041386

Answer (score 0):

try putting the source in single quotes

Comment: Hello Scott, I tried using single quotes but still get the error. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is a very complicate connection string, for the most part, all you need is the provider and file:

```
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\0datblaset\BlaSet\BLA-AssetMangment.mdb;"
```

A good place to check connection strings is http://connectionstring.com

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the provider. In my particular case, I had to change the DriverID to 1046, like my other connections that work.

```
DSN=ExcelFiles;DBQ=C:\Source\SourceFile.xls;DefaultDir=C:\Source\;DriverId=**1046**;
FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;
```

[image: My connection screenshot is attached]